# Save readline() as element not string

Tags: python

Ok,
Lets say I have a list of variable names in a file and I want to store them in a list.
I can make a while loop and append to the list 1 by 1 however they are saved in the list as strings. How can change this to a group of variable names.

```
list = []
f = open("text.txt",r)
f.readline()
while line != "":
    list.append(line)   
    f.readline()
```

I want list to be a list of variable names not a list of strings.
Thanks

Comment: What is a "variable name" if not a string? Do you want to look up the global variables whose names match each string, and store _those_ in a list? (If so, why? That's a pretty weird thing to do. It's doable, and I can explain how, but if you describe what your goal is, I can probably give you a better way to accomplish it.)

Comment: Off topic: Avoid using `list` as variable name.

Answer (score 5):

First, a variable name just *is* a string. So, you're already putting the variable names in a list.

If you're trying to look up the global variable named by each string, and put those variables into a list… well, you can't do that, because you can't put variables into a list. Variables aren't real things in Python, they're just (builtin, global, local, or qualified) names for values; it's the *values* that are real things.

But if you're trying to look up the global variable named by each string, and put the value of each of those variables into a list… that's easy. Change this line:

```
list.append(line)
```

… to this:

```
list.append(globals()[line])
```

---

However, your code has a number of other problems that mean it won't actually work. You've used the variable `r` instead of the string `'r'` as your file mode, which (unless `r` happens to coincidentally hold a valid mode string) will fail. You're also never assigning anything to `line`, and just throwing away the result of each `readline`, which means you're going to get an exception (or an infinite loop or a loop that immediately exits) trying to access it.

Meanwhile, most ways of reading files line by line, including `f.readline()`, leave the newline at the end of the string, and it's very unlikely that you have a variable whose name ends with a newline.

While we're at it, this is not very pythonic code. You should never name a variable `list`, you should always close your files, empty strings are false so you don't need the comparison, and you should use `for` loops to iterate over collections.

So:

```
values = []
with open("text.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        values.append(globals()[line.rstrip('\n')])
```

Or, more simply, use a list comprehension:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    values = [globals()[line.rstrip('\n')] for line in f]
```

---

Finally, this whole design goal smells very odd, and I'm willing to bet that it's not the right way to accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: +1 for very good explanation, even though it is not entirely clear what the OP is trying to do

Comment: @MarkkuK.: Well, my guess could be way off, in which case it's a good explanation of entirely the wrong thing… but let's keep our fingers crossed.

Comment: Your first code snippet (a copy & paste of the OP's) has a rather glaring error in it: you never actually store the value of `f.readline()` in `line`.  Also, the `readline` method leaves the trailing newline on, so you still need to do `.rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: @jwodder: The `rstrip` is already answered addressed further down as is at least one other glaring error. But you're right, on top of all the other problems already mentioned, the OP's code will raise a `NameError` on `line`. Let me edit the answer to address that.